# How do you write the cosecant function of a negative number as the trigonometric function of a positive number?

Tags: trigonometry

More specifically, how would you write $\csc(-2\pi/5)$ as the trigonometric function of a positive number?

Comment: sine (and hence cosecant) is an *odd* function. Basically, you can take the negative outside.

Comment: Just to clarify what Chaz is saying,

$$\sin(-x) = -\sin x$$ from where the same holds for the cosecant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Recall that  $\sin(x)=\sin(x+2k\pi)$ for any integer $k$. Let $x=-2\pi/5$ and let $k=1$.

Comment: This might be more in line with the *desired* solution than my comment above, but who knows! *"This answer is useful"*